# How to work with native resources in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm learning flutter right now and I want develop a app that use the smartphone camera, but I'm not finding anything in the flutter docs that help me with native resources of the smartphone. I basically want develop a app that user can use to cut a image and save it.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera ?

Comment: this is very useful, thank you, but my problem is to work with the image, cutting or redimensioning, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

With flutter you use plugins to access native API's. 
You can either create your own plugin using the following documentation 
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages 
or run an existing one from [www.pub.dev](https://pub.dev) like https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker